# how to check the Jboss (EAP 7) server running status via shell script

Tags: shell, jboss7.x

I have multiple jboss instance on a particular linux box . I don't want to grep the process id of jboss instance and listen port .Is there any work around from server.log or CLI command ?

Comment: try `systemctl status wildfly`

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the Panagiotis Chavarioti´s answer, the status of the application component also can be checked with the commands which are handy.

To check if JBoss server is started:

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c --commands="read-attribute server-state"
```

To check if application is started:

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c --commands="cd deployment,cd myapp.war, read-attribute status"
```

example:

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c 
'/host=sandbox/server=server1:readattribute(name=server-state)'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following CLI command:

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c 
'/host=<HOSTNAME>/server=<SERVERNAME>:readattribute(name=server-state)'
```